# Maximum possible acceleration value on a ball in volleyball game

Tags: classical-mechanics, acceleration, projectile, everyday-life

I have been examining this subject on web but could found enough information yet. I have to make a decision on choosing "range" for accelerometer which will measure acceleration value of ball in volleyball game.

What may be the possible maximum acceleration value for a ball in volleyball game?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Obviously the maximum acceleration is felt during an impact. Between impact with sand and impact with hand I think the hand would be worst case scenario.

Comment: Are you sure you meant acceleration and not velocity?

Comment: During impact the velocity changes rapidly over a short period of time. I consider this the max. acceleration condition.

Comment: Yes, peak accelaration occurs at impact in a short period. I need acceleration not volecity. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Since the ball is not rigid, you have to define what exactly you mean by acceleration.  (Center of mass? The part of the ball which is accelerated most?)

Comment: The ball changes velocity by 2v (from v to -v) over the distance of some fraction of the ball diameter while it hits a wall or the floor. Start with that.

Comment: There is a lot going on when a ball impacts something. Have you seen this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMqM13EUSKw